# Shoretel Reporting: does off-hook time count towards call length?

Tags: voip, reporting, shoretel

With Shoretel reports, the report that generates how long someone is on the phone (actively talking on the phone), if they are listed as "off hook", like right before you dial a number, does that still show up as being on a call?